# Como fechar conexões mysql no C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Ao executar o código abaixo:

```
    DataSet bdDataSet;
    MySqlConnection conexao;

    public void inserir()
    {
        bdDataSet = new DataSet();

        conexao = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=teste; Uid=; Pwd=");

        try
        {
            conexao.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("conectou");
        }catch{
            Console.WriteLine("Erro ao conectar");
        }

        if(conexao.State == ConnectionState.Open ){
            Console.WriteLine("conexao aberta");
            MySqlCommand commS = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO usuario VALUES('teste', 'teste')", conexao);
            commS.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

O registro é inserido normalmente, o problema é que se após o trecho:

```
MySqlCommand commS = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO usuario VALUES('teste', 'teste')", conexao);
commS.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
```

Caso eu execute `conexao.Close()` para fechar a conexão ele não executa o comando, como se ele não desse o `commit` na query e o `insert` não é feito, o que pode ser?

Answer (score 2):

[MySqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery executa uma instrução de forma *assíncrona* em relação ao banco de dados](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Asynchronous.html).

Isso significa que a query não é executada logo que o comando é dado, e sim no momento mais oportuno, **fora do fluxo de execução atual**.

Para resolver seu problema, você pode simplesmente usar *`ExecuteNonQuery`* ou chamar o término da execução assíncrona antes de fechar sua conexão:

```
IAsyncResult myResult = myCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery(null, null);
...
rowsAffected = myCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery(myResult);
```

Comment: O MySQL suporta eventos assíncronos, pois eu procurei a respeito à um mês atras mais ou menos e não tinha indícios de suporte...

Answer (score 2):

Execute a query da maneira demostrada abaixo:

```
DataSet bdDataSet;
MySqlConnection conexao;

public void inserir()
{
    bdDataSet = new DataSet();

    conexao = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=teste; Uid=; Pwd=");

    try
    {
        conexao.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("conectou");

        MySqlCommand commS = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO usuario VALUES('teste', 'teste')", conexao);
        commS.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }catch{
        Console.WriteLine("Erro ao conectar ou ao executar comando SQL");
    } finally {
        if(conexao != null && conexao.State == ConnectionState.Open ){
            conexao.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Note que, para executar a query o comando `ExecuteNonQuery()` é utilizado. Além disso, a conexão é fechada no `finally`, para que seja garantido que a mesma seja fechada.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você pode verificar se MySQL está configurado com autocommit ou não.

Dá uma olhada neste link [MySqlConnection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection.html). Lá tem informações e exemplo de código de como trabalhar com o commit manual.